# API versioning in Anypoint API manager

Tags: mule, versioning

I'm looking for a solution on how to deal with API versions in ANYpoint API manager. At the moment it is possible to create a new version of an API. But it is not possible to distinguish between different OTAP environment. In my situation it could be possible that a test environment has a newer API version than production. Do anyone recognize this issue and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there are no environment promotion capabilities per se in Anypoint Platform. Having said that, there are a number of things that you can do that can help in that regard, for example:
- You can export an API from Organization A and import it on Organization B.
- You may define different sub organizations, to reflect your OTAP environment structure.

In general, it is not strictly bad that on QA, Stage or UAT environment, you have a newer API version than in Production, if you plan to implement such version in there.

Just my 2c, Nahuel.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand if we want are going to create multiple apis then RAML versioning should be  followed. what i do i can share with others.

development raml version= 0.1.0
First major release version=1.0.0
if there is any minor change then we can do 1.0.1
if there is any major contract breaking change then we can use 2.0.0.